# Counting number of Days in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table that looks like this:

```
ID | Club Name   | Booking Date            | Submission Date 
---+-------------+-------------------------+-------------------------
1  | Basketball  | 2015-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 9/18/2015 3:23:42 PM
2  | Tennis      | 2015-10-14 00:00:00.000 | 9/28/2015 1:50:25 PM
3  | Basketball  | 2015-10-06 00:00:00.000 | 9/29/2015 11:08:20 AM
1  | Other       | 2015-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 9/29/2015 11:08:39 AM
```

I want to know how many times each club did a submission less than 15 days from the booking date..

The solution I came up with was adding a new column and running a the `datefiff` function and storing the value in the new column.. Then just grouping by club name and adding a parameter for > 15 on the new column..

The question I have is: can this be done on the fly with out having to create the new column? how much would that affect performance if its done on the fly?

Comment: Please explain why the down vote

Comment: Why not add the datediff in the where clause?

Comment: I agree that having datediff in the where is probably the best solution.. Just wanted to confirm and see if there was a better way of doing it...

Comment: So Sean you down voted because he didnt use datediff?  He did mention datediff.  Its a valid question.  I upvoted the question

Comment: @mvisser no I did NOT downvote this but glad you could jump to that conclusion.

Comment: I didn't give you the downvote but my guess is that it's because you can find questions very similar to this on StackOverflow.  The downvoter probably thought that this was a Google-able solution by searching for "compare dates in SQL" or some variation of that. However, it's a well written question and you let us know what you tried already; 2 out of 3 ain't bad ;).

Comment: @sean fair enough. Then I do apologise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be done inline, in a query.  In a database, you almost **never** want to store a calculated column, which is what that datediff column would be.  Instead, you can do the math in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(day, -15, BookingDate) >= SubmissionDate
```

I wrote that pretty quickly, so the date math might be going in the wrong direction (checking in the future instead of in the past) but playing with the above query should set you on the right path.  Just keep in mind that, if this table gets very big, you're going to be doing a TON of DATEDIFFs and that can have a performance impact.

Comment: just for people in the future reading this datefiff takes the datepart day not days...  DATEDIFF(day, -15, BookingDate) ...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Declare @Table table (Id int,Club_Name varchar(50),Booking_Date datetime,Sumbission_Date datetime)
Insert @Table values
(1,'Basketball','2015-10-21 00:00:00.000','9/18/2015 3:23:42 PM'),
(2,'Tennis    ','2015-10-14 00:00:00.000','9/28/2015 1:50:25 PM'),
(3,'Basketball','2015-10-06 00:00:00.000','9/29/2015 11:08:20 AM'),
(1,'Other     ','2015-10-21 00:00:00.000','9/29/2015 11:08:39 AM')


Select Club_Name
      ,Submissions= count(*)
      ,Early = sum(case when datediff(DD,Sumbission_Date,Booking_Date)<15 then 1 else 0 end)
 From @Table
 Group By Club_Name
```

Returns

```
Club_Name   Submissions Early
Basketball  2           1
Other       1           0
Tennis      1           0
```

Comment: Taking it a step further and counting how many submissions they had; I like it.

Comment: Just add ,Count=count(*)

Comment: this answer goes above and beyond the questions I was asking.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT ID,
    ClubName,
    Sum(Value) As Ttle
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
        ClubName, 
        COUNT(*) AS Value 
    FROM TableName 
    GROUP BY ID,
        ClubName, 
        RecordDate
    HAVING DATEDIFF(D, BookingDate, SubmissionDate)  > 15
) Data
GROUP BY ID,
    ClubName,
ORDER BY ttle DESC
```

Comment: Doing the grouping like is good for small data sets but to slow when you try to scale it up..